# How can I create an aggregate/summary pandas dataframe based on overlapping dates derived from a more specific dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The following dataframe shows trips made by employees of different companies:

source:

```
import pandas as pd


emp_trips = {'Name': ['Bob','Joe','Sue','Jack', 'Henry', 'Frank', 'Lee', 'Jack'],
        'Company': ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'HIJ', 'HIJ', 'DEF', 'DEF', 'DEF'],
        'Depart' : ['01/01/2020', '01/01/2020', '01/06/2020', '01/01/2020', '05/01/2020', '01/13/2020', '01/12/2020', '01/14/2020'],
        'Return' : ['01/31/2020', '02/15/2020', '02/20/2020', '03/01/2020', '05/05/2020', '01/15/2020', '01/30/2020', '02/02/2020'],
        'Charges': [10.10, 20.25, 30.32, 40.00, 50.01, 60.32, 70.99, 80.87]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(emp_trips, columns = ['Name', 'Company', 'Depart', 'Return', 'Charges'])

# Convert to date format
df['Return']= pd.to_datetime(df['Return'])
df['Depart']= pd.to_datetime(df['Depart'])
```

output:

```
  Name Company     Depart     Return  Charges
0    Bob     ABC 2020-01-01 2020-01-31    10.10
1    Joe     ABC 2020-01-01 2020-02-15    20.25
2    Sue     ABC 2020-01-06 2020-02-20    30.32
3   Jack     HIJ 2020-01-01 2020-03-01    40.00
4  Henry     HIJ 2020-05-01 2020-05-05    50.01
5  Frank     DEF 2020-01-13 2020-01-15    60.32
6    Lee     DEF 2020-01-12 2020-01-30    70.99
7   Jack     DEF 2020-01-14 2020-02-02    80.87
```

How can I create another dataframe based on the following aspects:

> 1. The original dataframe is based on employee names/trips.
> 2. The generated dataframe will be based on companies grouped by overlapping dates.
> 3. The 'Name' column will not be included as it is no longer needed.
> 4. The 'Company' column will remain.
> 5. The 'Depart' date will be of the earliest date of any overlapping trip dates.
> 6. The 'Return' date will be of the latest date of any overlapping trip dates.
> 7. Any company trips that do not have overlapping dates will be its own entry/row.
> 8. The 'Charges' for each trip will be totaled for the new company entry.

Here is the desired output of the new dataframe:

```
  Company      Depart      Return  Charges
0     ABC  01/01/2020  02/20/2020    60.67
1     HIJ  01/01/2020  03/01/2020    40.00
2     HIJ  05/01/2020  05/05/2020    50.01
3     DEF  01/12/2020  02/02/2020   212.18
```

I've looked into the following as possible solutions:

Create a hierarchical index based on the company and date.  As I worked through this, I realized that all this really does is create a hierarchical index but that's based on the specific columns. Also, this method won't aggregate the individual rows into summary rows.

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Company', not exactly sure how to say overlapping dates])
```

I also tried using timedelta but it resulted in True/False values in a separate column, and I'm not entirely sure how that would be used to combine into a single row based on overlapping date and company. Also, I don't think `groupby('Company')` works since there could be different trips and that non-overlapping that would require their own rows.

```
df['trips_overlap'] = (df.groupby('Company')
                   .apply(lambda x: (x['Return'].shift() - x['Depart']) > timedelta(0))
                   .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
```

Comment: Hard to tell as your input and output does not match exactly, but does `df.groupby(['Company', 'Depart']).agg({'Return': 'last', 'Charges' :'sum'})` do what you want?

Comment: Even though I triple checked my output, I missed that "01/06/2020" date.  For company 'ABC' in particular, all 3 trips have overlapping dates with the earliest departure as 01/01/2020 and the latest departure as 02/02/2020.  Since the three trips for ABC all fall within overlapping dates of each other, they would be grouped in a single row.  Therefore, the desired output would still be `ABC  01/01/2020  02/20/2020    60.67`.  The same goes for company 'DEF' as well since all three trips are within overlapping dates of each other.  Only 'HIJ' does not have overlapping trip dates.